# How to forbid copy or paste operation in NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

As the title mentions. How can I forbid the copy (Command + C) and paste (Command + V) operations in an `NSTextField` or `NSSecureTextField`?

Answer (score -4):

Create a subclass of UITextField. In that subclass, implement

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (sel_isEqual(action, @selector(copy:))) {
        return NO;
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Comment: I am using NSTextField (for OS X) instead of UITextField (for iOS). There is no such method in NSTextField.